# Is the Prelude of Bach's Cello Suite No. 3 (BWV 1009) in the form of A-B-A-C?

Tags: analysis, musical-forms

As an (elementary listening) exercise I am going through the 3rd Cello Suite and trying to recognize repetitions and phrases, etc.

I managed to get through all the movements, except the Prelude.  I was not expecting the dance-form ||:A:||:B:||; it is just that on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cello_Suites_(Bach)#Suite_No._3_in_C_major,_BWV_1009) they mention that the piece is in A-B-A-C form.

I can hear some of the phrases repeat, but I am having a very difficult time recognizing the A, B & C parts.

Could you please help me recognize the parts by providing time codes for this [scrolling video](https://youtu.be/wBhq2Gomupg?t=21) (or a video of your own choosing) that would mark the

- start of the A section
- start of the B section
- end of the B section
- start of the C section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia entry is, at best, misleading.

> The Prelude of this suite consists of an A–B–A–C form, with A being a scale-based movement that eventually dissolves into an energetic arpeggio part; and B, a section of demanding chords. It then returns to the scale theme, and ends with a powerful and surprising chord movement.

Section letters refer to musical repeats or identifiable sections, so the two A sections are expected to be identical, and the B and C parts should be clearly contrasting, with all comprising musically identifiable sections. However, the Prelude does not follow an A-B-A-C form in that sense. In fact, **the Prelude is through-composed**, meaning there aren't repetitions or clearly defined phrases/sections (and certainly no "movements" — another term the author abuses).

Instead, the Wikipedia author is using letters to describe musical texture. The mostly scalar parts are A parts, the section of broken chords is B, and the ending portion beginning with the block chords is C.

As best I can discern, the Wikipedia analysis breaks down as follows:

- A: mm. 1 – 36 (0:00 – 1:36)
- B: mm. 37 – 60 (1:36 – 2:25)
- A: mm. 61 – 76 (2:25 – 2:55)
- C: mm. 77 – 88 (2:55 – 3:30)

Comment: I see - I kept listening to it over & over again but couldn't piece together.  Thank you for clarifying it.  The nice thing with this type of exercise is that even when I don't succeed, I end up listening to great music :-)